# Making an ASP Label a clickable link to a document on a local server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Like the title says, I am trying to make a clickable link to a file on a local server. I am able to make it into a hyperlink, but when it is clicked it doesn't take me anywhere. This is the code I have:

```
Label1.Text = "<a href='File:///R:\DomainWebs\Intranet\fileups\TravelDocs\" & IncludeFileUpload.FileName & "'>" & IncludeFileUpload.FileName & "</a>"
```

if you need any other information let me know, thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: You cannot let browser access a file located outside of the web application folder. You either move the file inside the web application folder or create a generic file handler.

Comment: Have you tried using a [Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a label? The reason a label won't work the way you think it does, is because the `Text` field you're populating is _encoded_ so it will actually render the exact text you enter, as opposed to treating it as valid html.

Comment: @Win The folder is inside the web application folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File:///R:\DomainWebs\Intranet\fileups\TravelDocs\` means local folder. Due to security reason, a client browser is not allowed to access a file located outside of your web application.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to create a generic file handler.

### Usage

```
Label1.Text = "<a href='" & ResolveUrl("~") & "FileHandler.ashx?name=" & 
      IncludeFileUpload.FileName & "'>" & IncludeFileUpload.FileName & "</a>"
```

### FileHandler.ashx

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.QueryString["name"]);
            context.Response.TransmitFile("R:\\DomainWebs\\Intranet\\fileups\\TravelDocs\\" + fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log exception 
            context.Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

> The folder is inside the web application folder.

If so, you could just use the folder name. For that case, `HyperLink` server could be a better choice than `Label`.

```
 Label1.Text = "<a href='" & ResolveUrl("~") & "FolderName/" & 
   IncludeFileUpload.FileName & "'>" & IncludeFileUpload.FileName & "</a>"
```

Comment: To make sure that no directory traversal attack is possible, use Path.GetFilename() on the the value of QueryString["name"].

Comment: @AndrewMorton Good catch. I updated the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Win Yes, there is always the chance that someone has given the "Everyone" user access to the whole drive and so defeated the intended security in Windows.